# vb pc shutdown timer/falshing/and shutting down in 60 sec/ not 1 hour/even when its set for 1hour//

Tags: vb.net

```
    Timer1 . Start  ()

    Label1  .Text   = Format(Time Of Day)

    Timer2 .  Enabled = True
    TextBox1  .Enabled =   False
    Button2  .Enabled =   True
    Button1  .Enabled =  False

    Timer2.Enabled = False
    TextBox1.Text = "00:00:00"
    TextBox1.Enabled = True
    Button1.Enabled = True
    Button2.Enabled = False

    If TextBox1.Text = Label1.Text Then

    End If   
    Shell("shutdown -s")
```

I just want the pc to shut down when I get in to bed after a hour , because I am afraid that leaving pc on all of the time at night, will damage pc, i found this code on youtube

Comment: [Make Your PC Shut Down at Night (But Only When You’re Not Using It)](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/30758/make-your-pc-shut-down-at-night-but-only-when-youre-not-using-it/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the Task Scheduler approach proposed by Robert Harvey.

If you still want to code a "shut down one hour from now" application, then here's some starter code:

```
Public Class frmShutDown

    Private Target As DateTime

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Button1.Enabled = False
        Target = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)
        Timer1.Interval = 1000
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim TS As TimeSpan = Target.Subtract(DateTime.Now)
        Label1.Text = TS.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")
        If TS.TotalMilliseconds <= 0 Then
            Timer1.Stop()
            Shell("shutdown -s")
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```